# Querying of same columns with different values

Tags: mysql

Im just new to MySql Programming and Im creating a project to enchance my skills.
 I have a table called `tblRecipe` which has the columns `RecipeId, RecipeName and Instructions`. the other table is called `tblIngredients` which has the columns `IngredientId,RecipeId, IngredientName`.

Now for example,RecipeOne needs IngredientOne and IngredientTwo to make, RecipeTwo needs IngredientOne,IngredientTwo and IngredientThree to make.
My programs asks the IngredientNames for the input so when i put in IngredientOne and IngredientTwo it should give me back the result RecipeOne.

Here is my code

```
Select Recipename,Instructions 
from tblREcipe where RecipeId in 
         (select recipeID 
         from tblIngredients 
         where Ingredientname in('IngredientOne','IngredientTWo')
         );
```

I know that the IN operator is like saying match any of the following.
So with that code it gives me both recipes.
Im looking for an equivalent of AND.
I tried "Ingredientname =ALL(in('IngredientOne','IngredientTwo'))"
but it does not  return any rows.

Im open to any changes such as restructuring the tables if that fixes the problem since this is just a practice project.Hope to hear from you soon guys and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to `count` the number of instance of the records that match to the number of ingredients. Like this one below:

```
Select a.Recipename, 
       a.Instructions 
FROM   tblREcipe a INNER JOIN
         (
             SELECT   recipeID,
                      COUNT(IngredientId)
             FROM     tblIngredients 
             WHERE    Ingredientname IN ('IngredientOne', 'IngredientTWo')
             GROUP BY recipeID
             HAVING   COUNT(IngredientId) = 2    -- the number of ingredients
                                                 -- should somehow dynamic
         ) b ON a.recipeID = b.recipeID
```